# How to unfocus TextFiled When id dismis the keyboard in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

i have textField and triger the focus by button, but when i dismis the keyboard and i try to click the button for second time the keyboard is does not showing up, because the textfield still focused

```
  onTap: () {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(controller.textFieldFocus); 
  },
```

Comment: Have you tried `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()`?

Comment: I've tried it, but the the keyboard is still not showing up, just the textfiled is focused,

i'm sorry my english is bad.

Comment: Try this `onTap: () { FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(controller.textFieldFocus); }`

Comment: @mmcdon20 it still not working, the keyboard still not showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a working solution, (currently only tested on android emulator).

This is a small working example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late FocusNode node;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    node = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    node.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Focus Demo'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                node.unfocus();
                WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(node);
                });
              },
              child: Text(
                'Focus',
                style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.bodyText1,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: TextField(
          focusNode: node,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I was able to get it working by adding a delay between the unfocusing and refocusing using `WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback`.

In your case that should translate to something like this:

```dart
  onTap: () {
    controller.textFieldFocus.unfocus();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(controller.textFieldFocus); 
    });
  },
```

Comment: yeah it's work, thanks